# Who are the Moderators?

Tags: discussion, moderation

This proposal has a large amount of users, but none of them have over all of the Privileges if I am not mistaken. So this leads me to ask "Who are the Moderators? And how are they moderating?

When I click the moderation tab, nothing appears. This is not my first beta, but I was not able to be that active on the other ones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no moderators in the community other than the SE staffers, at the moment.

Here's how and when Stack Exchange chooses the pro-tempore moderators for a new site, quoting from [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/):

> About a week into the public beta, we will seek out members who are deeply engaged in the community’s development; members who:
>
> Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
>
> Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
>
> Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
>
> Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

For the time being, we are relying on SE staffers to take care of issues we can't take care of ourselves (responding to flags, for example).

Comment: That could be you ;-)